# Cannot access WebService stored on Windows Server 2003 from inside Windows Server 2003

Tags: web-services, authentication, web, windows-server-2003, accessibility

In all cases we are running .NET Framework 3.5

My company has a server running Windows Server 2003 R2 (Service Pack 2), 32-bit processor. The IIS instance on this machine runs several Websites. One of the Websites we are running is Microsoft CRM 4.

When I attempt to log in to CRM from my local PC, everything's perfectly straightforward. I receive a prompt for username and password, I enter the details, I'm authenticated, and I pass through. Easy.

However: I can RDP into the 2003 Server and open IE. If I then browse to our CRM website I am prompted for a username and password. I provide exactly the same details - including the correct domain - as I enter from my local PC. But nothing. I'm denied access.

I am an administrator both of my local PC and of the 2003 Server.

This is very weird. I don't even know where to *begin* looking on this one. I don't even know what key terms to hit into Google.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

---

**Context**

Now, knowing what developers are like (I am one) the first response is going to be: "If you can log in from your PC, why do you care?"

There's more going on.

We have another website on that server that does nothing but host a set of critical web services. This is because the critical web services themselves rarely change but the other features change all the time. We don't want the critical web services to go down while maintenance is performed on other areas, so they were split off into their own independent web site about 18 months ago.

I am developing a web service for the critical site. This Web Service itself includes a proxy that points to the CrmService of CRM 4. The idea is that we want people to be able to submit certain information - such as lead contact information - into our CRM. However, we don't want to give just anyone access to the whole CRM system (obviously). So by publishing our own WebService that sits in the middle we can expose only the functionality that we want other people to have.

This new web service is now ready for deployment. All scenarios are met, all unit tests pass, everything that should fail does. It's all hunky-dory.

When I put that WebService on the 2003 Server, suddenly it can't communicate with CrmService any more due to authentication failure. ???

In my attempts to diagnose the problem, I noticed that no-one - not even administrators - can log into the CRM Website from within the 2003 Server. So I'm suspecting that whatever is causing *that* issue is also responsible for my web service to be unable to access the CrmService too.

For additional context, we have a new multi-domain SSL cert on the 2003 Server and we're splitting access to all our websites via host-headers.

I can't think of any more relevant information. If I've left out something critical, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Did the trick.